# AWS unable to format iOS client http-header correctly

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, http-headers, nsurlrequest

I am unable to create a URL request in iOS Swift matching the following format in the **HTTPHeaders**:

```
{
    "Item": {
        "id": "eu-west-1:yadayada",
        "device": "amazingdeviceyadayadayadayada"
    }
}
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
  let scriptUrl = "https://amazingurl?serial=amazingdeviceyadayadayadayada"
    guard let myURL = URL(string: scriptUrl) else {
                print("Invalid URL")
                return
            }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("eu-west-1:identityidyadayada", forHTTPHeaderField: "cognitoID")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            // Check for error
            if error != nil{
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // Print out response string
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")  

    }
    task.resume()
```

Sadly, very sadly, when I run this from my client it does not work.

I suspect it is the way the HTTP header is formatted from the iOS client.

This is the variable of the request when I add a breakpoint to it:

> po request.allHTTPHeaderFields ▿ Optional> 
>   ▿ some : 1 element
>       ▿ 0 : 2 elements
>         - .0 : "cognitoID"
>         - .1 : "eu-west-1:identityidyadayada"

Any idea on **how I can format it correctly**?

Comment: Are you sure that is the header format you need to provide? The built in URLRequest class only supports `[String:String]?` as the header type, so you can't generate a header like that using the built in library. Also, use native Swift structs ( URLRequest). Does your request work from another environment, say, Postman?

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks for the reply. Yes it works perfectly from Postman, hence I imagine that is something to do with the way the URL is formatted.

Comment: If it works in Postman, have a look at how you input the headers there and try to to it the same way in Swift. You can also look at the Swift code Postman suggests you to use if you click on Code and choose Swift ( NSURL), maybe you just need to map the Dictionary into a String.